# Monetary question.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

You have 120 papers of dollars. The 10 dollar bills are 10 times the 5 dollar bills, and the others are 100 dollar bills. How many dollars you have ?
I tried to set vriables for the 10 dollar bills but things got messy. The question needs how much money you have in total. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Hint: let the number of $5$ dollar bills be $x$. How many $10$ dollar bills do you have? How many $100$ dollar bills do you have? BTW, to me it seems not solvable, as there may be many solutions (for example, one can have 10 papers of $5$, 100 papers of $10$ and 10 papers of $100$, hence in total 2050 dollar while other can have 5 papers of $5$, 50 papers of $10$ and 65 papers of $100$, hence in total 7025).

Comment: @Galc127 2050 is one of the choices, bravo.

Comment: @Laconic, in general, if one has $x$ papers of $5$ dollar, he would have in total $12000-995x$ dollars. You can take $x$ to be any integer number between 1 and 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 5,10, and 100 dollar bills here, call them $d_5,d_{10},d_{100}$ respectively.

We are given: 120 total bills.

$d_5+d_{10}+d_{100}=120$

and 10 times as many 10 dollar bills as 5 dollar bills.

$10d_5=d_{10}$

There is no information from which we can form a third equation, hence this linear system has 3 variables and 2 equations and is thus underdetermined. It has 1 free variable (the 2 given equations are linearly independent), hence there will be a line of infinitely many solutions. This line will include infinitely many integer solutions. If you have a set of possible answers, only one should satisfy the equation.